# NGinx Server Issue

Tags: nginx, server, digital-ocean

So I am using a Digital Ocean Server and I sued the LEMP build.

When I navigate to the /var/www/html directory, I see the two standard files that come with the build 'index.html' and 'index.php'.

Now my issue is, my Web App is Structured in such a way that the "index.html" file is located down another subdirectory "dist". (/var/www/html/dist/)

How do I configure Nginx to show this file?

Update:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    servername ***.**.**.**;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
```

Comment: Could you show us your nginx config for this webapp?

Comment: Where can I find this file? Sorry very new to nginx...

Comment: No problem, it's okay. Probably there is a file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ . It usually has the `.conf` extension, but not always, if you open the files in that folder, you can find one which has in the content something like  `server_name yourdomain.com`, send us that

Comment: Found it! See above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line in your configuration

```
    root /var/www/html;
```

and put this one

```
    root /var/www/html/dist;
```

**EDIT:**

And if you use a Debian based server (Ubuntu for example), do `sudo service nginx reload` on your console. If it doesn't work try `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: Sorry, try with the edit, I forgotten to say to restart nginx